# How To enter Special Characters in HTML editors and text box in php

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have developed a Quiz Contest Website in which admin can create questions and then those questions will be displayed .The Below is one of the question 
[image]

The above is a question which admin will enter but as you can see there are special characters such as Square Root Symbol and equilibrium sign.Please help me on this how admin can enter above question in the admin site.
I have a HTML Editor for entering question and have text boxes to enter it's options.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively new html5 library called MathML. See [MathML on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)

You can also play with unicode to achieve at least some of the symbols. see [this example link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm)

In general its best to just upload images that contain those special symbols. you can easily generate this kind of equations with [latex](http://www.latex-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The methods of entering special characters such as ⇌ (U+21CC) and √ (U+221A) depend on the environment: operating system, keyboard settings, installed auxiliary software, etc. You might consider linking to instruction pages such as http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm but basically this is something that each user has to solve himself, unless you wish to enhance your HTML editor with special functionality.

(The vinculum associated with the square root sign cannot be produced directly at the character level – combining overline isn’t really suitable for it –, and although it can [drawn in various ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/#uol), it probably does not pay off in a context like this.)

Your HTML editor of course needs to be Unicode-enabled

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would write it in [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) or [word-equation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-an-equation-using-equation-editor-HP005190247.aspx) and take a screenshot and upload it as an image. That would be the easiest way.